# How to automatically switch sound output to Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, alsa, headphones

How do you make Ubuntu 16 automatically switch sound output to Bluetooth headphones when they connect?

Currently, my Bluetooth and sound work perfectly, except whenever I want to use my headphones, I have to open settings, go to sound, and select the headset for output. I'd prefer it to work like cell phones do, where if a Bluetooth headset is connected, it automatically switches to that.

This is similar to this [old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589885/automatically-switch-sound-output-device-to-bluetooth-headset-force-to-a2dp-pr), but Ubuntu 16 doesn't come with Pulseaudio, nor do I want to screw up my perfectly working Alsa setup by installing it. I did try some of the methods suggested there, and naturally none of them work anymore.

Comment: " Ubuntu 16 doesn't come with Pulseaudio" Ubuntu and it's official flavors come with and use pulseaudio since 6+ years.

Comment: @xangua, Then why isn't it listed as a running service with `sudo service --status-all`?

Answer (score 3):

Might not be your final goal, but as a workaround, you could use a little app called [Sound Switcher Indicator](https://github.com/yktoo/indicator-sound-switcher).

Sound Switcher Indicator is a sound input/output selector Ubuntu AppIndicator. It allows switching the current sound input and output (source and sink) as well as the specific output port with just two clicks.

**Install Sound Switcher Indicator in Ubuntu**

Sound Switcher Indicator is currently available in a PPA for Ubuntu users. Add the PPA and install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yktooo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-switcher
```

Refered article:
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/sound-switcher-ubuntu-indicator.html

Answer (score 1):

This is also not fully automatic, but at least more convenient:
If you are using gnome, this extension does its job quite well [Sound Output Device Chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/)